# Adjust Weight Size to Become Smaller Using Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Below is the coding using Latex to generate 3 nodes and 3 edges graph, as seen in the picture. It works perfectly, with only one small problem. So, each edge has 7, 31, 31, which represent the weight of the edge.

My question is, how to increase the number size (7, 31, 31) so that it will become bigger and look clearer. I want the coding to increase the size of the weight. I will get the same result, but the edge weight (7, 31, 31) will look bigger in the picture.

I attach the second picture; as you can see, the weight (7,31, 31) becomes bigger in their size, but the other parts remain the same—just a perspective like that.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\centering

\newcommand\rad{6.5}

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}  

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=7cm,on grid,initial/.style    ={}]

  \node[state]          (S1)  at (120:\rad)    {$S1$};

  \node[state]          (S2)  at (240:\rad)    {$S2$};

  \node[state]          (S3)  at (360:\rad)   {$S3$};

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=orange}}

\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}}

\path (S1)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$7$}   (S2)

      (S2)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$31$}  (S3)

      (S1)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$31$}  (S3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The question about the weights is not very clear to me. You could edit your question and add an image of the result of the posted code and an image of what you want different. Do you want to change the position of the nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but you can say `mystyle/.style={->,double=orange,font=\footnotesize}` to reduce the font size used for printing the weights.

Comment: Your question is not Overleaf specific. It is about how to draw images by `tikz`. Please, correct question's tags accordingly.

Comment: I have edited my question and put the output image for a better prespective and understanding. Thank you

Comment: I have edited the second time. The way I 'want' is like the second picture. Of course, it still has its own direction, and each node is specified as S1, S2, S3 like the first picture. But, the perspective I want can be seen in the second picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
state/.append style = {minimum size=1.8em, inner sep=0pt},
  every edge/.style = {draw=orange, semithick, 
                       -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white, font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
\newcommand\rad{1.44} % for distance ~ 1cm between nodes
%
\node[state]    (S1)  at (120:\rad)    {$S1$};
\node[state]    (S2)  at (240:\rad)    {$S2$};
\node[state]    (S3)  at (360:\rad)   {$S3$};

\path (S1)  edge ["$7$" ]   (S2)
      (S2)  edge ["$33$"]  (S3)
      (S1)  edge ["$33$"]  (S3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**
If you like to have positions of nodes somewhere else, than you need to select different coordinates positions. In above MWE (Minimal Working Example) coordinates follows to coordinates defined in your MWE. They are defined in polar coordinate system: `<angle>:<distance` where in your case the starting point for coordinates is considered `(0,0)`.

If positions of nodes you change to for example

```
\node[state]    (S1)  at (180:\rad)    {$S1$};
\node[state]    (S2)  at (270:\rad)    {$S2$};
\node[state]    (S3)  at ( 60:\rad)   {$S3$};
```

then resulted image is:

[image]

Of course, you can define cartesian coordinates of nodes. For example, using relative coordinate system:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
state/.append style = {minimum size=1.8em, inner sep=0pt},
  every edge/.style = {draw=orange, semithick, 
                       -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white, font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
%
\node[state]    (S1)  at (0,0)  {$S1$};
\node[state, above right=1cm and 1.4cm of S1]   (S2)    {$S2$};
\node[state, below right=1.4cm and 1cm of S1]   (S3)    {$S3$};

\path (S1)  edge ["$7$" ]   (S2)
      (S2)  edge ["$31$"]   (S3)
      (S1)  edge ["$31$"]   (S3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, from (basic) geometry follows, that equal distance (about 1cm) is possible, if nodes are symmetrical placed on plane, i.e. that they lie on circle.  Radius of circle you can calculate. This is simple, if you with distance you consider distance between centers of nodes.

[image]

**Edit (2):**
From your comment below, now follows, that you concern is only edge label font sute. It is all MWE in my answer determined by code line:

```
every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white, font=\Large} % <--- here you can set font size of edge labels
```

which is at use above settings gives:

[image]

If `\Large` is not sufficient, you can change it to `\huge` or even `\Huge` predefined font size, or define own size with

```
font=\fontsize{<desired size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont
```

for example `font=\fontsize{24pt}{28pt}\selectfont` for some silly big size for edge labels:

[image]

Comment: My problem is not changing the position of the weight like you show. My problem is changing the 'font size' of the weight. I want to make weight look bigger in 'font size'.

Comment: @KamenRider, sorry, your question is not entirely clear about this. Even more, showed images in edited question is mostly concern about node condition. However, font size of edge labels can be simple change. See edited answer.

Comment: @KamenRider, any news?